# How to write if/ else function?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a function for my shopping cart that displays the product list when "data" is passed to it, but when there is no "data" available, I would like the cart to return "Empty Cart". Can I do this with a if/else statement? The code is below.

```
const propductList = (data) =>{
      console.log(data)
       setTotal(data)
    }
```

I guess what I want to do is something like this

```
const productList = (data) =>{
console.log(data)
if (data) setTotal
} else return "Empty Cart"
}
```

The full code is below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {
    removeCartItem,
    onSuccessBuy
} from '../../../_actions/user_actions';
import UserCardBlock from './Sections/UserCardBlock';
import { Result, Empty, Button } from 'antd';
import Paypal from '../../utils/Paypal';



function CartPage(props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    console.log(props)
    const [Total, setTotal] = useState(props.location.state.data.price)
    const [ShowTotal, setShowTotal] = useState(true)
    const [ShowSuccess, setShowSuccess] = useState(false)
    
    const removeFromCart = (productId) => {
        dispatch(removeCartItem(productId))
            }
        
    const transactionSuccess = (data) => {
        dispatch(onSuccessBuy({
            cartDetail: props.user.cartDetail,
            paymentData: data
        }))
            .then(response => {
                
                    setShowSuccess(true)
                    setShowTotal(false)
                }
            )
    }

    const transactionError = () => {
        console.log('Paypal error')
    }

    const transactionCanceled = () => {
        console.log('Transaction canceled')
    }
    const propductList = (data) =>{
      console.log(data)
       setTotal(data)
    }
    return (
        <div style={{ width: '85%', margin: '3rem auto' }}>
            <h1>My Cart</h1>
            <div>
            {props.location.state.data &&
        <UserCardBlock
          productData={props.location.state.data}
          removeItem={removeFromCart}
          productList={data => propductList(data)}
        />
}
 {ShowTotal ? (
          <div style={{ marginTop: "3rem" }}>
            <h2>Total amount: ${Total * 15} </h2>
          </div>
        ) : ShowSuccess ? (
          <Result status="success" title="Successfully Purchased Items" />
        ) : (
          <div
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
          >
            <br />
            <Empty description={false} />
            <p>No Items In The Cart</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>

            {/* Paypal Button */}

            {ShowTotal &&
                <Paypal
                    toPay={Total}
                    onSuccess={transactionSuccess}
                    transactionError={transactionError}
                    transactionCanceled={transactionCanceled}
                />
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default CartPage
```

Comment: what is setTotal method? is it the useState?

Comment: See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Comment: yes, it is the useState

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
const productList = (data) =>{
    if (data) return setTotal(data)
    else return "Empty Cart"
}
```

Or even shorter in a ternary operator:

```
const productList = (data) =>{
    return data ? setTotal(data) : 'Empty Cart';
}
```

Or even shorter directly doing the ternary as return:

```
const productList = data => data ? setTotal(data) : 'Empty Cart';
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It says not that productList is undefined now. Is there any way to fix that?